# conditional weak convergence almost surely and joint unconditional weak convergence

Tags: probability, statistics

Sorry for the confusing title!

Consider random variables $\{X_n, Y_n:n\geq 1\}$, defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$. Suppose,

(i) $X_n \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} Z$,

(ii) $Y_n\mid X_n \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} Z$, almost surely $(P)$. This is the same random variable $Z$ as considered in (i).

Assume $Z_1,Z_2$ are iid with the same d.f. as $Z$. Then, I need to show that, unconditionally, 
$$
(X_n, Y_n) \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} (Z_1, Z_2).
$$
Also, will this be true if almost surely is replaced with in probability $(P)$ in part (ii) above. Any references, ideas will be highly appreciated. This is mentioned as a statement in page 475 of the book by Dasgupta (Asymp. Theory of Stat and Prob.).
Thanks!

Comment: The paper 'Some Limit Theorems for Joint Distributions ' by Sethuraman may be related. https://www.jstor.org/stable/25049174?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: What is $Y_n|X_n$? Do you mean $E(Y_n|X_n)$? If so, then the claim is false, because we could take $Y_n=X_n$, and there's no independence.

Comment: @ChristianRemling The statement '$E(X_n|Y_n) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} Z$ almost surely $(P)$' has no immediate meaning. Unless I am mistaken, the statement is rather to be understood in the sense that, almost surely, the conditional distribution of $Y_n$ given $X_n$ converges weakly to the distribution of $Z$. This is in line with the context of the statement in the book, as well as the paper mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: Y_n|X_n is the conditional distribution of Y_n given X_n. There is a similar exercise (Ch 6, Problem 6) in the book by Hajek, Sidek and Sen (on Rank Tests). Their formulation is slightly different. I did it by using characteristic functions. I guess this problem can be done similarly, but I haven't tried. In any case, this result is highly useful in studying unconditional distribution of bootstrapped estimators.

Comment: @JonasDahlbæk I will look into this paper closely. Thanks for looking it up.